# Función recursiva en C++

Tags: c++, funciones, lógica

Estoy resolviendo un problema llamado superdígito, para más información aquí os dejo el enlace al problema, es un problema muy interesante que vale la pena leer además de que es muy importante para que sepan de qué estoy hablando. (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/recursive-digit-sum/problem)

El punto es que ya lo resolví, sin embargo sin hacer uso de la función recursiva, así que ahora estoy intentando resolverlo con recursividad, no sé mucho de C++ y se me está complicando, el problema viene cuando intento sumar todos los números de un vector es decir

`v = {1,2,3,4}` //Por ejemplo

La suma sería igual a 10
Esto lo quiero resolver con una función recursiva que se llama "sumalos" y recibe 1 parámetros, la longitud del vector, la primera vez funciona, yo le paso los números, imprimo el valor y me regresa la suma correcta, pero en la segunda vuelta del ciclo no me retorna el valor correcto, tal vez sea de mi otra funcion llamada "guardaDigitosDeVector", pero no estoy seguro, este es todo mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
    int p = 0, k = 0, v = 0, aux = 0;
    vector <int> n, suma;


    int sumalos(int n){
        if(n > 0){
            return suma[n] + sumalos(n-1);
        }
        else {
            suma.clear();
            return suma[0];

        }
    }

    guardaDigitosEnVector(int k){
        if(k>0){
            n.push_back(k%10);
            return guardaDigitosEnVector(k/=10);
        }
    }

    guardaDigitosEnVector2(int k){
        if(k>0){
            suma.push_back(k%10);
            return guardaDigitosEnVector2(k/=10);
        }else{
            return k;
        }
    }



int main(){


    cin>>p>>k;

    guardaDigitosEnVector(p);

    reverse(n.begin(), n.end());
    for(int i = 0;i<k;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<n.size();j++){
            suma.push_back(n[j]);
        }
    }

///27:50

    while(suma.size() != 1){

        for(int i = 0;i<suma.size();i++){
            cout<<"Suma[i]: "<<suma[i]<<endl;
        }

        v = sumalos(suma.size());

        cout<<"Valor de v: "<<v<<endl;

        cout<<"Guarda digitos en vector: "<<guardaDigitosEnVector2(v)<<endl;

        cout<<"Longitud de suma: "<<suma.size()<<endl;
        cout<<"Se acaba el ciclo"<<endl;
    }

    ///cout<<suma[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tu código no compila. Las funciones no tienen indicado el retorno y a la función `guardaDigitosEnVector` le falta un `return` cuando `k <= 0`. Partiendo de esto, o has copiado un código que no es el que estás probando o es que no has probado nada porque ya te digo que eso así no compila. Te recomiendo depurar, cuando consigas que compile.

Answer (score 1):

El objetivo de una función recursiva es llamarse a si misma hasta una condición de parada. Aqui te muestro la función para calcular el superdigito de cualquier número usando recursividad:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int cifras(int numero)
{
    string num = std::to_string(numero);
    return num.length();
}

int superdigito(int numero)
{
    if(cifras(numero) == 1)
    {
        return numero;
    }
    else
    {
        int cifs = cifras(numero);
        int super = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < cifs; i++)
        {
            super += numero % 10;
            numero /= 10;
        }
        return superdigito(super);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int numero = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        cout << "Introduzca un numero para calcular el superdigito, -1 para salir: ";
        cin >> numero;
        if(numero < 0)
            break;
        cout << endl << "El superdigito de: " << numero << " es: " << superdigito(numero) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```